# How to create a function that outputs the largest number using conditions in c++

Tags: function, c++11, conditional-statements

/*Description: Write a function called getMax that takes three parameters of type int, and returns the biggest of the
    three parameters which is of type int.
*/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Declare the function getMax and put in three variables.


int getMax(int number, int number2, int number3){
    if( number >= number2 && number >= number3){
        cout << number;
        if(number2 >= number && number2 >= number3)
            cout << number2 ;

    }
    else {
        cout << number3;
    }
    return number, number2, number3;
}
```

// we now use the function to check for largest values below:
    int main(){

```
    cout << getMax(-13, -22, -3) << endl; //Prints -3
    cout << getMax(9, 8, 9) << endl; //prints 9
    cout << getMax(-5, 4, -7) << endl; //prints 4
    cout << getMax(15, 15, 15) << endl; //prints 15
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Aside: [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) has an overload that takes any number of parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it this way:

```
int getMax(int number, int number2, int number3){
    return number > number2
            ? (number > number3 ? number : number3)
            : (number2 > number3 ? number2 : number3);
}
```

Without ternary operators you can write:

```
int getMax(int number, int number2, int number3){
    if (number > number2) {
        if (number > number3) {
            return number;
        }
        return number3;
    }
    if (number2 > number3) {
        return number2;
    }
    return number3;
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind. Can you please write code without the Ternary operators? I am new to C++ and my professor has not really covered this topic. Thanks.